# uploading a php file to server using php

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I have the below code... This is the second file that is being uploaded by the form, but I keep getting an error.  I am attempting to upload a .php file.  I am using the same code to upload a .jpg and it works fine!

```
 $allowedExts = array("php");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file2"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file2"]["type"] == "image/php"))
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {

  if ($_FILES["file2"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file2"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "<br /><br />Upload: " . $_FILES["file2"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file2"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file2"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file2"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("trip/" . $_FILES["file2"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file2"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file2"]["tmp_name"],
      "trip/" . $_FILES["file2"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in:" . "trip/" . $_FILES["file2"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file2";
  }
```

Comment: to upload 2 files in one form?

Comment: really bad idea... that is like leaving a cake around fat people...

Comment: @user3015838 No.  To allow users to upload php files to your server.  Also, last I checked, `image/php` isn't a valid MIME type.

Comment: Ahh it is just for me, to make updating easier.

Comment: will be password protected etc

Comment: the MIME type worked.  thanks daedalus

Answer (score 0):

Uploading .php file is really insecure and I wouldn't recommend doing that.
However, if you really want to do this for learning or any other reason, the error is here:

```
"image/php"
```

PHP's MIME type is not `"image/php"`. Try `"text/php"`.

Answer (score 0):

remove this

```
if ((($_FILES["file2"]["type"] == "image/php"))
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
```

or write the extensions correctly because there are no image with php extension

will be like this

```
if (
($_FILES["file2"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
($_FILES["file2"]["type"] == "text/php")
)
{
```

here image have extensions jpeg,png,... and text have extensions like php,html,...